# ESP8266 WiFi isn't working without WiFiMulti

Tags: iot, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, esp8266wifi

I did a project for IoT attendance system using ESP8266 and RDM6300. However, I can connect to wifi using WiFiMulti.addAP() function for my home WiFi but can't connect using WiFi.begin().

I tried **WiFi.begin() instead of WiFiMulti.addAP()** function to connect to my mobile hotspot but the esp8266 is failing to connect. In fact, **WiFi.begin() also failed to connect to the same wifi router which was previously connected by WiFiMulti.addAP()**. Serial monitor constantly showing the below error.

```
Exception (3):
epc1=0x4020970d epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x4003bfc9 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffbc0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01a0
3ffffd60:  00000000 00000004 3ffffe40 3ffffef0  
3ffffd70:  4010156c 0000049c 000003fd 40209837  
3ffffd80:  0000049c 00001000 000003fd 4010156c  
3ffffd90:  40106980 3ffe85ad 3ffffe40 402354f1  
3ffffda0:  401004a5 402355db 3fff0c1c 0000049c  
3ffffdb0:  000003fd 3ffffef0 3fff0c1c 402355be  
3ffffdc0:  ffffff00 55aa55aa 00000035 00000020  
3ffffdd0:  00000020 00000048 0000004a aa55aa55  
3ffffde0:  000003ff 40235aa8 3fff0c1c 3fff0c1c  
3ffffdf0:  000000ff 3fff0c1c 0000049c 00000000  
3ffffe00:  401004a5 00000001 3fff0c2c 40235cc2  
3ffffe10:  00000008 3fff0c1c 000000ff 3ffffef0  
3ffffe20:  3fffff10 3fff0c53 00000035 00000020  
3ffffe30:  3fff0cdc 3fffff51 00000001 40235d72  
3ffffe40:  3ffffef0 40242be0 00000000 0000000c  
3ffffe50:  3fff101c 3fffff10 3fff6f54 40235d41  
3ffffe60:  3fff0c1c 40235da8 3ffe84dc 3ffe85ae  
3ffffe70:  402019ca 3ffe85ae 3ffe85b3 40201927  
3ffffe80:  61666152 00000074 3ffffe60 40204666  
3ffffe90:  4000e243 00000030 3ffffe60 402046c4  
3ffffea0:  616d7374 2e2e3730 3ffffe00 40204901  
3ffffeb0:  3ffffdf0 0693b740 000035af fffffffe  
3ffffec0:  00000090 3fffc6fc 00000003 40201dd4  
3ffffed0:  3ffee50c 000000f2 000000f2 40206bf8  
3ffffee0:  8ab9b001 00a0a64e 00000000 40206057  
3ffffef0:  78666152 3fff0c00 0000049c 00000000  
3fffff00:  00000a2e 0000007f 3fff0c1c 402356c6  
3fffff10:  61666172 66617274 32317461 40209500  
3fffff20:  00000001 3fff0c1c 00000000 402099e8  
3fffff30:  000003fd 402351a3 00000000 40101538  
3fffff40:  00000001 001ce8e7 3ffeea78 402351be  
3fffff50:  40235100 00000001 00000081 00000002  
3fffff60:  00000004 00000000 3ffee544 00000001  
3fffff70:  402083ea 000003e8 000003e8 3ffee870  
3fffff80:  3ffee544 00000000 3ffee750 40201194  
3fffff90:  00000000 00000000 ffefeffe feefeffe  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee840 40207830  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8520 40101809  
<<<stack<<<

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
~ld
```

this is the code I uploaded to ESP8266:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClient.h>

#include <rdm6300.h>

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);

#define RDM6300_RX_PIN 2
#define READ_LED_PIN 14

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
Rdm6300 rdm6300;

String RFID[] = {"5958666", "5958741"};

String SID[] = {"161-115-123", "161-115-124"};

String NAME[] = {"Rafat", "Saney"};

int flag[2] = {0, 0};

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  pinMode(READ_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(READ_LED_PIN, LOW);
  rdm6300.begin(RDM6300_RX_PIN);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  OLED("Connecting...");
  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin("custom", "customjack.xyz");
  Serial.print("Connecting");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected");
  OLED("Connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
label:
    OLED("Place Your ID");
    String tag;
    int check = 0;
    if (rdm6300.update())
    {
      tag = String(rdm6300.get_tag_id());
      Serial.println(tag);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
      {
        if (RFID[i] == tag) // checking validity of RFID
        {
          tone(READ_LED_PIN, 392);
          delay(100);
          noTone(READ_LED_PIN);
          check = 1;
          if (flag[i] == 1) // Flag=1 meaans already attendance counted
          {
            Serial.println("Attendance Already Counted");
            OLED("Already Counted");
            delay(2000);
            goto label;
          }
          OLED("Welcome "+NAME[i]);
          flag[i] = 1;
          WiFiClient client;
          HTTPClient http;

          Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
          String url = "http://metrounisas.000webhostapp.com/action.php?ID=" + SID[i];
          if (http.begin(client, url ) ) { // HTTP


            Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
            // start connection and send HTTP header
            int httpCode = http.GET();

            // httpCode will be negative on error
            if (httpCode > 0) {
              // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
              Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

              // file found at server
              if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
                String payload = http.getString();
                Serial.println(payload);
              }
            } else {
              Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
            }

            http.end();
          } else {
            Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
          }
        }
      }
      if (check == 0) {
        tone(READ_LED_PIN, 261);
        noTone(READ_LED_PIN);
        Serial.println("Invalid RFID");
        OLED("INVALID ID");
        delay(2000);
      }
    }
  }

  delay(1000);
}

void OLED(String txt){
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE,BLACK);
  display.setCursor(30, 30);
  display.println(txt);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue in the delay after `"."` so the solution is to add delay around 500ms before it like this:

```
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
}
```